# Cannot align divs horizontally alongside eachother with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to display information from the database using PHP and CSS. However when I style the information it is displayed vertically, one after another. I wish to display the information in containers, side by side each other.

When i add the code `<div class="w3-row-padding w3-third"` to my first div, it displays the containers really small and all over my web page. I have removed the `w3-third` and it goes back to displaying vertically. I have created `design` and called the ID to make the alteration to the div, although nothing has changed still.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

CSS

```
                    <style>

        design {
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
```

}

```
    </style>

          $con=new mysqli("localhost:3308","root","","fypdatabase");
        $st=$con->prepare("select * from personal_trainer where specialty=?");
        $st->bind_param("s", $cat);
        $st->execute();
        $rs=$st->get_result();
        while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<div id="design" class="w3-row-padding" style="margin-top:64px">
<div id="design" class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
  <div id="design" class="w3-card">
        <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" style="width:100%"/>
        <div class="w3-container">
        <p><h3>'.$row["name"].'</h3></p>
        <p>'.$row["location"].'</p>
        <p>'.$row["fee"].' EUR</p>
        <p>'.$row["numberTWeeks"].' Weeks</p> 
        <p>'.$row["email"].'</p>
        <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i><a href="addItem.php?personalTrainerID='.$row["personalTrainerID"].'"> Purchase</a></button>
    </div></div></div>
    </div>';
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

```
<div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
 <div class="w3-card">
    <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" style="width:100%"/>
    <div class="w3-container" style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;">
      <p><h3>'.$row["name"].'</h3></p>
      <p>'.$row["location"].'</p>
      <p>'.$row["fee"].' EUR</p>
      <p>'.$row["numberTWeeks"].' Weeks</p> 
      <p>'.$row["email"].'</p>
      <button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i><a href="addItem.php?personalTrainerID='.$row["personalTrainerID"].'"> Purchase</a></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Hi Arthur thank you for your response! Unfortunately that didn't work! Its still in vertical format.

Comment: do you place the <div> with `style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;"` outside of the loop?

Comment: @Sebastian yes i put it in the first line! Any suggestions to change?

Comment: Hi Daran,

Sorry I didn't read your code properly. YES the idea is to create a container div with the style "display:flex"
All your child divs should be horizontally aligned.

Comment: No problem at all! So i created an element of css called "design" and put in those two pieces, then i called the ID in the div however nothing has changed. Sorry my css is quite poor ive updated the question!

Comment: It won't work like that.
First you need to specify how your style is referenced :
#design {...} pointing to an element whose id is "design" (your case)
.design {...} for elements whose class is "design"

Then you only need to apply display:flex to the parent element, not the children.

Answer (score 0):

this bootstrap did work though not php guy
check this out

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
`your left hand side contents here`
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
`your right hand side contents here`
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you thats great! However it displays still vertically, as whats in my echo statement loops through my db, it doesnt display horizontally in this instance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **span**-Tag instead, this is almost the same as a **div** but it displays side-by-side with other tags, while **div**-Containers are designed as a block and will be displayed vertically.

I recommend using tables, your code could look something like this:

```
<?php
    $con=new mysqli("localhost:3308","root","","fypdatabase");
    $st=$con->prepare("select * from personal_trainer where specialty=?");
    $st->bind_param("s", $cat);
    $st->execute();
    $rs=$st->get_result();

    echo '<table class="table">
        <col style="width:100px;"><!--first column-->
        <col style="width:;"><!--second column--><!--if you leave value empty, its responsive-->
        <col style="width:100px;"><!--third column-->

        <tr><!--table headers-->
            <th>image</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>location</th>
            <th>fee</th>
            <th>numberTWeeks</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        ';
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" style="width:100%"/></td>
            <td><p><h3>'.$row["name"].'</h3></p></td>
            <td><p>'.$row["location"].'</p></td>
            <td><p>'.$row["fee"].' EUR</p></td>
            <td><p>'.$row["numberTWeeks"].' Weeks</p></td>
            <td><p>'.$row["email"].'</p></td>
            <td><button class="w3-button w3-light-grey w3-block"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i><a href="addItem.php?personalTrainerID='.$row["personalTrainerID"].'"> Purchase</a></button></td>
        </tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';        
?>
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, thats great! I've changed it originally from table format, im trying to work on design now which is why im using this bootstraps and divs! I just cant get the output to flow horizontally